# Combining Preprocessed data and drilldown in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a while. I am a little bit of a beginner with highcharts and javascript and I have hit this problem and I do not know how to solve it and any help is well appreciated.

I have a highcharts chart that reads in a .csv file and takes the data and creates a chart automatically with yAxis and xAxis names and categories etc. What I was trying to accomplish was to add drilldown functionality to this chart. The drilldown chart has preprocessed data as well, but for the time being I am trying to set the drilldowns in the data like so http://jsfiddle.net/yw4Vh/

`series: [{data: [{ name: 'Fruits', y: 10, drilldown: 'fruits'`

but for some reason when I loop through my code its like I cant set the drilldown for each row. I also get no error for my javascript code so I am stuck. **I have seen many other examples online but this has not helped me, so please if possible if you could not just link some code without explaining, it would help a lot. This is my code, in particular this part is where the problem is I think. How can I assign series.name to series.data.drilldown for each row.** ?

Link to my code : http://jsfiddle.net/vF5C8/1/

```
$.get('prof2.csv', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(';');


                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);

                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else {
                    var series = { 
                        data: [],
                        visible:false,
                        type: 'column'

                    }
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                            series.data.drilldown = 'item';

                        } else {
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }

                    });


                    options.series.push(series);

                }

            });

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

Sample code from my .CSV file

```
1995;1996;1997;1998;1999;2000;2001;2002;2003;2004;2005;2006;2007;2008
Ál;18461;27588;20862;25185;27946;20323;22082;;;;;;;
Bles;3237;2947;3185;3245;3319;3563;3710;;;;;;;
Díl;2550;2980;2762;1894;1657;2161;3352;;;;;;;
Dugg;101;173;232;86;183;204;238;;;;;;;
Fýll;8059;8920;10093;9037;7739;10495;10323;;;;;;;
Gr;35350;37657;41240;38017;35038;32510;35692;;;;;;;
Háv;2022;1860;1556;1496;1843;1949;1924;;;;;;;
Heið;10695;12182;14674;15396;13903;14271;12557;;;;;;;
Hel;1876;1619;2629;2283;1376;1412;1409;;;;;;;
Hett;2958;2696;2854;2306;1910;1527;1274;;;;;;;
Hra;7119;6653;5987;5564;4555;3087;3884;;;;;;;
Hreir;329;361;260;300;406;359;462;;;;;;;
Hvít;3942;4546;3771;3187;5496;4251;3111;;;;;;;
Kj;2617;2292;1993;1752;1302;1293;1183;;;;;;;
Lan;52867;65179;59529;65612;59797;66567;52839;;;;;;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how do you link points and series (drilldowns). You have now:

```
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: '1994',
            data: [
                ['AU', 14],
                ['NE', 21],
                ['NV', 12],
                ['SU', 15],
                ['VE', 16],
                ['VF', 34]
            ]
        } ... ]
```

So ID for series is `1994`. Now, when you have points in 1st level series:

```
            $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo == 0) {
                    series.name = item;
                    series.data.drilldown = 'apple'; // remove that - it's just wrong

                } else {
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item)); //adding points to series
                }
            });
```

You should add for each point, `drilldown` property, to link with drilldown series, like this:

```
                    series.data.push({
                        y: parseFloat(item),
                        drilldown: '1994' // must match with `id` in drilldown.series
                    }); //adding points to series with drilldown
```

And that's all. You just need to determine which point drill downs to which series.

Comment: Thank you so much. You literally helped me a huge amount. Thank you.

Comment: Then just accept my answer (near the 0-value - green sign ;) ).